# Unable to pg_restore SQL file on remote Linux VM

Tags: linux, postgresql, virtual-machine, pg-restore

I am using PostgreSQL as my DB.

I have **SCPed** a **.sql** file on my remote Ubuntu VM.

I did `sudo su - postgres` and create a DB.

then I switch backed to my original account and tried this:

`sudo -su postgres pg_restore < temp.sql`

The command ran successfully.

But when I again switched back to **postgres** user and checked the db for the list of tables using **\dt** I found no tables.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

'pg_restore' is meant to restore files generated by 'pg_dump'.

From the man page

> pg_restore is a utility for restoring a PostgreSQL database from an
>   archive created by pg_dump(1) in one of the non-plain-text formats.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgrestore.html

If your file was generated by pg_dump you probably need to at least tell it which database to dump into:

```
pg_restore -d my_new_database temp.sql
```

My own experience with pg_restore across different flavors shows that many times I need to specify the format of the dump file, even if it was in 'native' format, despite the manpage indicating that it would detect the format.

```
pg_restore -d my_new_database -Fc temp.dump
```

This is only a guess, but I'm thinking if the tables actually restored, without specifying the db, they got dumped into the default database. You can check this by listing the tables in the 'postgres' database (there should be none).

```
postgres=#\c postgres
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres".
postgres=#\dt
No relations found.
```

If your tables did restore into the default database they will be listed.

Plain text SQL files need to be treated differently, usually executed via SQL commands using psql.

```
psql -d my_database < temp.sql
```

Comment: I had created the dump and marked the option to create the database 'yes'. So I thought, I wouldn't need the database name. However after specifying the database name it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @ameitection - Glad I could help! You're not the only one that has been tripped up by that. I suspected because it happened to me.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you generated your database backup similar to this:

```
pg_dump -a --inserts databasename > exportfilename.sql
```

Try restoring your file like this:

```
psql databasename -f exportfilename.sql
```

Postgres `pg_restore` as mentioned above is only meant to be used with `dump` files, you can't restore it like that. Check for this answer in the official postgres.org website

Basically you *don't* use `pg_restore` with `sql` files --->
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTi%3DAqmWrUR4f8%2BEfCHzP%2BQrL1%3DunRLZp_jX7SoqF%40mail.gmail.com

Comment: is there a special directory where this backup file has to exist?

Comment: the backup file can be created anywhere in your local system

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when running the `psql` command from within the terminal with `ubuntu` user. The command would end with an `out of memory` error.

I then switched to the postgres user with `sudo -i -u postgres`.

From there I simply run `psql databasename -f databasefilebackup.sql`, as mentioned above.

Comment: did this databasefilebackup.sql exist within a particular directory or can it be anywhere on my computer